# Re-scan wireless networks in cmd without disconnecting from current WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, batch-file, vbscript

I'm creating a `batch-file` that executes a command once a specific WiFi network is available in the list of networks. I've managed to get the script working, but to accelerate the detection process (>3 minutes) I need to execute a `wifi-scan` again.

As the network detection process will happen in the background, using the solutions on a [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/889414/force-refresh-re-scan-wireless-networks-from-command-line) *won't work* as the device needs to remain connected to a WiFi network during the process.

As far as I know this is not possible in CMD alone. **My question is:**

**How can I scan for new WiFi networks in CMD using either**

- A native command
- VB Script
- A pre-compiled EXE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force refresh (re-scan) wireless networks from command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/889414/force-refresh-re-scan-wireless-networks-from-command-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try Wireless net view by NirSoft

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_network_view.html

run it with the /scomma  switch

[Save the list of wireless networks into a comma-delimited text file (csv).]

then do a for loop on the output file with a comma delimiter

for example:

```
wirelessnetview /scomma wifi1.txt

for /f "delims=," %%x in (wifi1.txt) do if "%%x"=="myWifi" echo found
```